# About $e^{3iz} = e^{3ix}e^{-3y}$ being bounded in upper plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, inequality

> [image]

What does $e^{3iz} = e^{3ix}e^{-3y}$ being bounded in the upper plane ($Imz > \epsilon$ ?) mean? Because $$|e^{i3z}|^2 = e^{i3z}\overline{e^{i3z}} = 1$$

So what is wrong with saying

$$ \left | \frac{e^{i3z} + e^{-i3z}}{2(z^2 + 4)} \right | \leq  \frac{|e^{i3z}| + |e^{-i3z}|}{|2(z^2 + 4)|} \leq \frac{1 + |e^{-i3z}|}{|2(z^2 + 4)|}\leq \frac{1 + 1}{|2(z^2 + 4)|} $$

Now I know that RHS $\to 0$, so something is wrong.

Comment: $$  |e^{i3z}|^2 = e^{i3z}\overline{e^{i3z}} = e^{i3(z - \overline z)}  = e^{-3 Im(z)  }$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $|e^{3iz}| = 1$ if and only if $z \in \mathbb{R}$ is real.  Otherwise, we have $|e^{3iz}| = e^{-3y}$ where $y$ is the imaginary part of $z$.

If $z$ is in the upper half-plane, then $y \geq 0$ and $|e^{3iz}| = e^{-3y} \leq 1$ is bounded by $1.$

On the other hand, if $y$ could be an arbitrarily large negative number, then $|e^{3iz}|$ would be unbounded, so to control that absolute value, we need to assume $y \geq r$ for some real number $r,$ and the natural choice is $r=0.$

Comment: $|e^{3iz}| = |e^{3ix}e^{-3y}|= |e^{3ix}||e^{-3y}| = |e^{-3y}|$. In the upper half plane $Im(z) = y > \epsilon$ and thus $e^{-3y} < e^{-3\epsilon} < 1 \stackrel{\epsilon \to 0} \leq 1$. I am just writing this for myself.

Comment: In the principal value, how come $e^{i3x}$ is left over? Doesn't that $=1$ in $|.|$?

Comment: @Hawk In line (3), we haven't taken the absolute value, so there's no reason for the numerator to become $1.$  Presumably in the next part of the proof, we would be evaluating the principal value integrals by replacing $x$ with $z$ and choosing some contours in the complex plane around which we can integrate using basic estimates and the residue theorem.  None of this would work if we replaced the numerator with its modulus in the beginning.

Comment: I think they implicitly set $y = 0$.

Comment: @Hawk In the beginning, we are dealing with an integral over the real line, so $z = x + 0i.$  In the next step when we deal with contour integration in one of the upper or lower half planes, we would have nonzero imaginary parts.